# No such token: 'btok_1JGm2oKFR93cFUSYN2bui4Yb' when i try to create a Bank Account for Stripe Customer

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

Whenever i create a Bank account token using plaid/stripe integration and proceed to use this to create a Stripe bank account for my customer it keeps on returning the No Such token error.
Now i have gone through other questions posted here that suggest to check if the environments match i.e if my stripe keys are test keys and if my Plaid is in Sandbox mode.
They are both in test modes but it still fails.

````
PLAID_ENV = sandbox
const client = new plaid.Client({
  clientID: PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
  secret: PLAID_DEV_SECRET,
  env: plaid.environments[PLAID_ENV],
  options: {
    version: '2020-09-14', // '2020-09-14' | '2019-05-29' | '2018-05-22' | '2017-03-08'
  }
});```

My stripe is using the Stripe Test keys. I confirmed the accounts are linked. 
Any help figuring out why it still returns this error would be appreciated
````

Comment: Did you ask Stripe support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No such..." errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account).

Comment: Thanks it was a mismatch of account keys, the client handed me access to a different Stripe account from the one linked to Plaid